# Properly detach the LUKS header from the existing FDE+LVM encryption

Tags: debian, lvm, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

There are many other questions about the detached LUKS header here, but none solve my problem.

I am attempting to relocate my existing included header from `sda2` to a separate raw partition on device `sdb1`.

After removing the original header, the system fails to start and halts at the `initramfs` console.

OS: LMDE 5 (Linux Mint Debian Edition = de facto Debian 11)
Standard LVM installation on LUKS2

I did the following steps:

1. `cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda2 --header-backup-file /header.img`
2. `dd if=/header.img of=/dev/sdb1`
3. option `header=/dev/sdb1` > `/etc/crypttab`
4. `update-initramfs -u -k all`
5. `cryptsetup luksErase /dev/sda2`

Up to this point, everything works fine and the system boots up properly.

When, according to the instructions in the [cryptsetup FAQ §2.20](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/main/FAQ.md) I do:

6. `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb1` > `Data segments: offfset: 16777216 bytes`
7. `dd bs=512 count=32768 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2`

the system no longer starts.

After many hours of research, I have a hunch that the UUID and signatures are to blame (or complicit) because there was a header reset. But that's just a hunch and I have no proof of it.

Have I screwed something up or am I missing a step?

Comment: Create a random LUKS block elsewhere and copy its header instead of zeroing: this decoy should help detection, even if it won't actually be used.

Comment: Zeroing the LUKS header means you can no longer identify it by UUID, this can be an issue with changing device names; if it gets stuck in initramfs you might need to adapt your bootloader parameters (kernel parameters, /proc/cmdline), not just crypttab.

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you for your information! Is the adaptation of these parameters very complicated or can you help what and how should be modified? It seems that this is the only solution for me to achieve the intended goal. If you feel like helping me, I guess it can be as an answer (not a comment) because it will be a solution to the problem and the right answer.

Comment: @DarekH I can only guess since it's not in your post. You should check your bootloader / kernel cmdline configuration - and adapt accordingly. Post your kernel parameters and also crypttab. If you wish to identify sda2 by UUID you'll also have to put a new header on it (can be a LUKS header w/o any keyslots, just for the sake of providing a new UUID). This external header setup is a bit unusual and just not as well supportes as "regular LUKS" so you have to jump some hoops. The external header itself does not hold any reference to the device it should open so you have to specify it yourself…

Comment: @A.B Poking around in the configuration of the kernel, bootloader + who knows where else seems too dangerous for me. I believe that I am too weak in these matters and I am afraid of unforeseen consequences. I'll stick with the idea of ​​a "dummy header", which brings additional benefits in case of "losing" the computer > good luck to the adversary who tries to brute-force this disk with this header ;)